# how to validate the autocomplete combobox so that the user does not type outside the autocomplete list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, combobox, autocomplete

how to validate the autocomplete combobox so that the user does not type outside the autocomplete list in vb.net. So I want the user to have to select the list from the autocomplete combobox instead of typing manually and also on pressing the keyboard backspace then the user cannot press the esc keyboard key because that can also create outside the list. is it possible that it could be implemented?.

Maybe the code I made is still wrong so please guide me

Thanks

```
Private Class Item
        Public Property Codeproduct() As String
        Public Property Barcode() As String
    End Class
    Private source As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private items As List(Of Items) = Nothing
    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        items = New List(Of Items)()
        items.AddRange({
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "TEST",
            .BARCODE = "1000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Andrea",
            .BARCODE = "2000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Arnold",
            .BARCODE = "3000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Barbara",
            .BARCODE = "4000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Billy",
            .BARCODE = "5000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Clint",
            .BARCODE = "6000"
        },
        New Items() With {
            .CODEPRODUCT = "Cindy",
            .BARCODE = "7000"
        }
    })
        source = New BindingSource()
        source.DataSource = items
       
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(items.Select(Function(n) n.CODEPRODUCT).ToArray())
        Dim ComboBox1Bind As New Binding("Text", source, "CODEPRODUCT", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        AddHandler ComboBox1Bind.Parse, Sub(s, evt)
                                            source.CurrencyManager.Position = items.FindIndex(1, Function(r) r.CODEPRODUCT.Equals(evt.Value))
                                        End Sub
        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(ComboBox1Bind)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = source
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "CODEPRODUCT"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CODEPRODUCT"
    End Sub
```

RESULT from answer

[image: RESULT from answer]

Comment: You should spend a bit of time learning how data binding works. What you have is still fairly wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What you have could still do with some work. Firstly, your code couldn't even compile because you have a class named `Item` but then you create new `Items` objects; a type that doesn't even exist. Also, these lines are pointless and possibly detrimental:

```vb
Dim ComboBox1Bind As New Binding("Text", source, "CODEPRODUCT", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
AddHandler ComboBox1Bind.Parse, Sub(s, evt)
                                    source.CurrencyManager.Position = items.FindIndex(1, Function(r) r.CODEPRODUCT.Equals(evt.Value))
                                End Sub
ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add(ComboBox1Bind)
```

You should configure as much as you can in the designer and then only use code to do what you must. For this example, I added the `BindingSource` in the designer and also completely configured the `ComboBox` there. The only thing I needed to do in code with the `ComboBox` was set the `DataSource`. Here's the relevant designer code:

```vb
Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
Me.ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CodeProduct"
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Barcode"
```

Note that the `AutoCompleteSource` is `ListItems`, not `CustomSource`. As I said in your other question, you can use the list items as the autocomplete source. Note that the `ValueMember` is NOT the same as the `DisplayMember`. The whole point of this sort of binding is that the user sees a friendly name and selects from that list, then you get the identifier from the `SelectedValue`.

The user code then looks like this:

```vb
Private Class Item
    Public Property CodeProduct As String
    Public Property Barcode As String
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim items As New List(Of Item) From {New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "TEST",
                                             .Barcode = "1000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Andrea",
                                             .Barcode = "2000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Arnold",
                                             .Barcode = "3000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Barbara",
                                             .Barcode = "4000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Billy",
                                             .Barcode = "5000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Clint",
                                             .Barcode = "6000"
                                         },
                                         New Item() With {
                                             .CodeProduct = "Cindy",
                                             .Barcode = "7000"
                                         }}

    BindingSource1.DataSource = items
    ComboBox1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
    If ComboBox1.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso
       Not String.Equals(ComboBox1.Text,
                         ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem),
                         StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        'The displayed text does not match the text of the selected item so it is invalid.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The list of items is created and bound to the control. On the `Validating` event, we check that the displayed Text matches the text of the selected item. If it doesn't then that means that the entered text does not match a list item so we don't let the user shift focus until they change it.